# Targeting Specific Divs

Tags: jquery, html, targeting

Ok, what I'm trying to figure out it how to use jQuery to work out which `div` is currently selected, highlights, etc and then to apply code to that `div`.

For example, I have three `div`s lined up in a row.  Each `div` has a `class` of `.box`. Within each `div` is another `div` with a class of `.overlay`.  By default `.overlay` is set to `display: none;`, but when I roll the mouse over each `div` I want to overlay for THAT `div` ONLY to get set to become visible - all the other `div`s overlay should remain hidden.

Take a look, http://jsfiddle.net/j76s2/

I've got the JS to get the overlay to show when the mouse rolls over the `div`s, but it shows all the overlays whenever you roll the mouse over any `div`. I know why that's happening but what I can't work out is how to get the code to work out that is should only show the overlay for the first `div` when that `div` has the mouse over it and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.hover()` event which takes two functions, one for hoverin and one for hoverout.  And, then you can use `this` as the context for the currently hovered `.box` element to find the `.overlay` in it and then use `.hide()` and `.show()` to change it's visibility.

```
$(".box").hover(
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay").show()},
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay").hide()}
);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wa5Bn/

You may also like to use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` like this:

```
$(".box").hover(
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500)},
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500)}
);​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4qeqm/

Comment: I added a `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` option.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to refer to specific element with `this`:

```
$(".box").mouseover(function(){
    $(".overlay", this).css({"display" : "block"});
});

$(".box").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".overlay", this).css({"display" : "none"});
});
```

This way you are narrowing the selection to a `.box` element contained inside hovered element.

Also, consider using `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of `.css()`.

Comment: @moonwave99 Thanks for your help.  Why would you suggest .hide() and .show() instead of .css()?

Comment: @user1563944 less characters, more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the CSS for all of the elements with the `.overlay` class. To just affect the one that you are currently mousing over, you should use `$(this)` to select the current element, and then `find()` to locate the class that is contained within it.

```
$(".box").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").css({"display" : "block"});
});

$(".box").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").css({"display" : "none"});
});
```

​